# Range of $f(x)=ax^2-c$

Tags: functions, quadratics

The function $f(x)=ax^2-c$ satisfies $-4\le f(1) \le -1$ and $-1\le f(2) \le 5$. Which of the following statement is true ?

(1)$-7\le f(3) \le 26$

(2)$-4\le f(3) \le 15$

(3)$-1\le f(3) \le 20$

(4)$-\frac {28}{3}\le f(3) \le \frac {35}{3}$

My approach is as follow

$f(1)=a-c$

$f(2)=4a-c$

$f(3)=9a-c$

$-4\le a-c \le -1$ and $-1\le 4a-c \le 5$

We need to find $a'\le 9a-c \le b'$, how do I proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, consider how to express $f(3)$ as a linear combination of $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ so you can effectively use their adjusted limits to determine the limits for $f(3)$. To do this, for some real constants $d$ and $e$ you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
9a - c & = d(a - c) + e(4a - c) \\
& = (d)a - (d)c + (4e)a - (e)c \\
& = (d + 4e)a + (-d - e)c
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Matching the coefficients of $a$ and $c$ between the left & right sides gives

$$d + 4e = 9 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$-d - e = -1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Adding \eqref{eq2A} and \eqref{eq3A} gives $3e = 8 \implies e = \frac{8}{3}$ which, substituting back into \eqref{eq3A} gives $-d - \frac{8}{3} = -1 \implies d = -\frac{5}{3}$. This now gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(3) & = 9a - c \\
& = - \frac{5}{3}(a - c) + \frac{8}{3}(4a - c) \\
& = - \frac{5}{3}f(1) + \frac{8}{3}f(2)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Next, you've got

$$-4\le f(1) \le -1 \implies \frac{20}{3} \ge -\frac{5}{3}f(1) \ge \frac{5}{3} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

$$-1\le f(2) \le 5 \implies -\frac{8}{3} \le \frac{8}{3}f(2) \le \frac{40}{3} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Adding \eqref{eq5A} and \eqref{eq6A} gives, from using \eqref{eq4A}, that

$$\frac{5}{3} - \frac{8}{3} \le - \frac{5}{3}f(1) + \frac{8}{3}f(2) \le \frac{20}{3} + \frac{40}{3} \implies -1 \le f(3) \le 20 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

This matches option ($3$).

Comment: Just a simple question: For a quadratic function (f), is it always true that f(n) can be expressed as a linear combination of f(n - 1) and f(n - 2)?

Comment: @Mick No, I don't believe you can in general express a quadratic function $f$ as a linear combination of $f(n-1)$ and $f(n-2)$ because the quadratic function $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ has $3$ undetermined coefficients so it can't be expressed as a linear combination of just $2$ equations involving those coefficients, so it's an underdetermined system. It was possible to use a linear combination here because it's quadratic function of $f(x) = ax^2 - c$ has only $2$ coefficients.